# different result 22/7 on python 2.7.12 and 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

how to make output `22//7` on python 2.7 become `3.14159` ?i try use `float(22/7)` but it just give me `3.0`. I try use `Decimal` but it just give me `3`, use `round(x, 6)` only give `3.0` just like `float`.

Comment: try `float(22.0/7)`

Comment: `float(22)/7`. One number needs to be of type float. `float(22/7)` fails because the result is already evaluated through integer division before casting the result to float.

Comment: Simply use 22./7, this will cast the result as a float

Comment: `from __future__ import division` then use `//` if you *want* integer division.

Comment: I hope that no python version will give you a result of 3.14159 for 22/7, because that would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, int/int will return int only that is what happening here 22/7 gives 3 and you're type casting it to float(3) which is giving 3.0 but if you will perform float/int or int/float then it will result into float so you convert any of them to float as shown following.

replace `float(22/7)` with `float(22)/7`